# Linking to Hotmail's Junk folder?

Tags: outlook.com, links

How would I create a link that takes a given user, who is logged in to Hotmail in their browser, straight to their Hotmail's junk folder?

We're a new website and we send out a verification code via email, but Hotmail users have trouble finding our mail because it usually lands in the spam folder (and no, we're not spamming at all). In Gmail for instance it's pretty easy to link to a search in:all so the user will find it even if it's sorted in spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Junk folder ID is 5 (fid=5).

You can use this link:

`https://mail.live.com/mail/InboxLight.aspx?n=1&fid=5`

I modified the `n` variable to be sure that it wasn't required to be specific because it was a longer number when I first logged in.

Also note, there is a number of subdomains that they'll be redirected to, but it looks like whether they are logged into their account or not they'll land in their junk folder. I tried this on an incognito window to be sure it worked and was redirected to the junk folder.

just for notation sake, the original link looked like this:

`http://bl174w.blu174.mail.live.com/default.aspx#!/mail/InboxLight.aspx?n=1217260055!n=1466329077&fid=5`

Comment: Thanks so much, that's terrific! I now realized that sending people straight to the Junk folder is also not quite enough; what I'd really want to do is to send them to a search in their Hotmail which covers both Junk and Inbox (like we do in Gmail; after all, our mail may not be sorted in Junk after all). Should I post a new question?

Comment: Yes, you should post that as a new question, but doing a quick look at hotmail they don't allow searching the junk folder. I tried and this is the message I got: `We didn't find any results for "folder:"Junk"". Do you want to start from scratch with an advanced search?` I have one junk message in my inbox.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, just linking to the Junk folder is probably already a far superior solution -- after all, people will still likely see our message in the inbox next time they go there (but they likely won't visit the Junk folder on their own).

Comment: GREAT idea! (Linking to spam folder). I'm working on something similar and this is a better solution than *instructions* for finding the spam folder)